# Debugging through Android source code while running in device with lower SDK level than the target SDK

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, android-studio

I've been trying to figure out how to debug through android source code in cases that the device is not running under the target SDK but a lower api level.

Here is an example to clarify the question:

Target SDK: 19
Device running SDK 16

When I try to debug through the android source code, the attached source code belongs to the target sdk version (in this case 19). As you can imagine the source code does not match the running device sdk level (in this case 16), so it's almost impossible to have a real debugging session.

I also have downloaded the source code for the device running api version.

Does anybody know how to attach the correct source code for a debugging sesion under a sdk version lower than the target sdk version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30054969/939193 ?