# Android studio shows sources from API of compileSdkVersion when debugging on device with older API

Tags: android, api, debugging, android-studio

I am debugging with Android Studio (A.S) 1.0.2 with compileSdkVersion 21 set up in build.gradle.
When using an emulator with API 21 everything works fine.
The problem occurs when debugging on a device having API 19.
Each line in the call stack (tagged as 'Frames' in A.S) correctly shows the function name, source file and line number that matches API 19.
However, when I click on one of the lines that corresponds with one of the framework sources (e.g. Activity.java), A.S incorrectly opens up and displays the API 21 version of the file rather than the API 19 version.

In my android sdk folder I have both
./sources/android-19 and ./sources/android-21

Any idea why A.S displays the wrong version of the file?

Things I tried (in order):

- Resetting Android Studio (by removing ~/.AndroidStudio*)
- Update Android Studio to latest version
- Running on emulator with API 21 - A.S shows the correct version (21) of the files.
- Changing compileSdkVersion to 19 and running on API 19 device - A.S shows the correct line numbers in call stack and opens the correct version (API 19) of the files in the correct line.
- Changing compileSdkVersion to 19 and running on API 21 emulator - A.S shows, in the call stack, the line numbers corresponding to API 21 (which seems to me as the correct behavior), however, when clicking on it, A.S mistakenly opens up the API 19 version of the file rather than the API 21 version.

To summarize, when clicking on a line in the call stack A.S opens up the version of the file  represented by compileSdkVersion and not the one used by the device/emulator during the debug session.

Comment: I'd like to find a solution where `compileSdkVersion` is set to 21 and Android Studio automatically shows the correct sources when debugging on API level 19 device. I don't want to switch `compileSdkVersion` at all, since my builds should be against API level 21.

Answer (score 7):

Answered with working solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32236703/1267536

Full content:

I use appcompat support library quite a lot. Changing the compileSdkVersion only results in massive compile errors. If you are using appcompat-21, you must compile against api 21 or you will get compile errors.

This works fine if you are debugging against version 21. But when you are debugging on Jelly Bean (API 17), your debugger keeps dropping you to the API 21 source. Very annoying and hard to debug.

The solution I've ended up using is very hacky but works! Let's say you are trying to debug against API 17. Do the following:

1. mv $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-21 $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-21-orig
2. cp $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-17 $ANDROID_HOME/sources/android-21
3. restart android studio so it will pick up the correct paths.
4. Debug

Just don't forget to put all the directories back after you're done.

Here's an android studio bug report about this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183976

Comment: Just to make this "hack" a little easier to use i wrote a basic node js cli app that does the renaming for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/android-source-swap

Answer (score 3):

Open your project in Intellij Idea (Android Studio based on it) and choose `File -> Project Structure...`. In project setting select "project SDK" to version which you need debug and select for all project modules "project SDK" as module SDK. After that you can attach debug connection to your device/emulator and see proper Android source.

You don't need to build project in Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 3):

Change temporary the folder name of source files in the SDK. 
For example you compiled against API level 23 but the device you're testing and debugging is API level 15. Then first compile and run it in debug mode, set a breakpoint. After that switch the names :

```
$SDK_HOME$/sources/android-23/ -> $SDK_HOME$/sources/android-23-temp/
$SDK_HOME$/sources/android-15/ -> $SDK_HOME$/sources/android-23/
```

And when this is done then it is a good time to hit your breakpoint.

This solution is assuming that you've installed both API level sources from SDK manager.

Comment: That's an excellent idea. That should also work for Logcat (which is still not fixed as of version 4.0.1 of Android Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging your app on a real device, compiling with the device's SDK level. The line numbers in the call stacks will probably be "out of sync" for classes provided by the device.

Android Studio can't reliably provide the correct sources for your running device. Even if it would take into account the SDK version of the device you are debugging on, the device's firmware could (and propably will) still be compiled from different source files and just be compatible to the API.

I think that's why Android Studio just shows the compile SDK versions of the classes provided by the target device. It just shows the compiler's reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[Link to issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77315) that tracks this problem.

Android Studio 2.2 fixes it, and will jump to sources of API level that corresponds to the device that you're actually running on (as long as you have those sources installed). It was announced [here](https://youtu.be/hHnTIMjd1Y8?t=27m37s).

Comment: This doesn't work on 2.3.3.  Maybe it was dropped or maybe, like so much from jetlag brains, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work also on AS 3.4.2
Sometimes they make me crazy, they introduce new features when there is a lot of bugs left!

Comment: Still doesn't jump to the right source when clicking in Logcat view.

Comment: Still not working in the new shiny Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (new version numbering scheme). Just shows me the compiled SDK version of sources.

Comment: still not working in Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1