# Android Studio steps into wrong sdk source

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I've got the following build.gradle settings.

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

The problem is that when I step into Android SDK source on an KitKat device (19 on Genymotion or Device), it still insists on stepping into Android-21 source instead of 19.

Changing any of the above settings simply breaks the compilation of my app since I have v21 code. All 19 calls are protected properly and the code *works* on 19, just the source code linkup is incorrect.

Cheers in advance Stack Overflow brothers and sisters!

Comment: Please review your AndroidManifest.xml file and make sure those values are not defined there also. Sometimes sdk version and build tools are also defined in the manifest.

Comment: I wouldn't assume this is necessarily supported.  If you want to debug on API 19, perhaps the simplest will be to (temporarily) build against that.  Or you could try to fake it out with symlinks in the source directories (ie, specify api 21 so the build jar is right, but symlink it's source jar to the api 19 one) or some obscure IDE setting.  **Why do you need to trace through the source of Android itself?**  That should rarely be needed, and keep in mind that a lot of the functionality is on the other side of an IPC you can't trace through anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : When you step into the android.jar(19) that resides on a device then you should be stepping in the source code that it was built with, NOT the source code my app was built against. "Why do you need to trace through the source of Android itself?" Heaps of reasons. At least twice a day I step into the SDK (on 21 only because of this issue). Right now I trying to offer cross sdk support and they're functioning different under the hood. I'd like see why by stepping through.

Comment: How do you expect the debugger to manage that?  If this is a real and urgent need, rather than being head down in a debugger, you'd probably do better looking at diffs of versions of the source - *assuming* of course that Android as actually installed on your device reflects the corresponding version of upstream sources to begin with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The android on the device is AOSP so it was stepping correctly into the source before I started to support v21. How would my debugger know that the android.jar was v19? Good question....

Comment: @John Twigg I have the same issue here. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Same issue over here... I would like to debug device's API level 18 ListView but it steps into target sdk API level 22 ?! anyone figured out how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android studio shows sources from API of compileSdkVersion when debugging on device with older API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671859/android-studio-shows-sources-from-api-of-compilesdkversion-when-debugging-on-dev)

Answer (score 12):

Android Studio 2.2 fixes it (mostly), and will jump to sources of API level that corresponds to the device that you're actually running on (as long as you have those sources installed). It was announced [here](https://youtu.be/hHnTIMjd1Y8?t=27m37s).

---

Although the fix in Android Studio 2.2 works for public/standard builds, if the device is using a custom build (ie they made some changes to parts of the framework and assigned it a proprietary build id) then the 'fix' will not find the most closely matching source. The following technique is useful to get a version of the source *that more closely matches* the corresponding API level:

1. Compile the application without any changes.
2. Launch the application in Debug mode (and optionally break on breakpoint).
3. Go to `File` > `Project Structure`, find your `app` module (or/and optionally, any other modules) and change the `Compile Sdk Version` to one that matches the device you're debugging on (i.e. 19).
4. Step into the framework code - it should step into SDK 19 sources.

**Warning:** This causes Studio to sync and reevaluate your code and *may* cause problems.  So changing this temporarily may get you the right source code, but you may have to change it back to build the next time. (as @Null Pointer points out)  This is an imperfect, but useful technique.

Comment: While this works, it fails miserably if you are using appcompat support library.

Comment: Great workaround! Or you can directly modify "compileSdkVersion" of build.gradle to your target level then click sync, it does the same thing. :)

Comment: This changes the build path, the question is how to change the source path, which you need to have match your target device if stepping into SDK source.

Comment: It does not seem fixed. I'm using AndroidStudio 2.3 but still it shows the wrong file. When I step into View.java it shows me the one from SDK API-25 (as my compileSdkVersion) but it's running into an API 23 device.

Comment: This doesn't work, it changes build.gradle and immediately sync project and closes debugger, eventually it fails to compile app. That's plain wrong advice.

Comment: @PointerNull Not sure what you mean by "This doesn't work" and "That's plain wrong advice". As I mentioned in my 2016's edit, the workaround is not required anymore. I've just verified (AS 3.5, multiple emulators) the problem doesn't reproduce, and AS steps into correct source file. If you still experience problems - they are most probably environment-specific, and I'd suggest you to file a bug.

Comment: @AlexLipov When I change SDK during debugging as you advice, Studio immediately tries to sync project files and stops debugging. So the 4 steps in your answer don't work. Maybe you need to mark them as obsolete method, because it just confused me.

Comment: @PointerNull Got you. I've strikethoughed original workaround to prevent confusions.

Comment: @ARLabs The 'fix' may not work because your device may claim a proprietary version of the framework.  AS then can't find the correct sourse code.  Using Alex Lipov's technique lets you select a closely matching set of source code -- that I have found to be much more helpful than the grossly changed current code base.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, AS 2020.3.1, target = 30 (android 11), actual device = 28 (android 9). And its a Google Pixel XL, so you would hope they have the source !

Answer (score 12):

As was mentioned in another answer, it was fixed in Android Studio 2.2 ([bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37006628)).

However, it still wasn't working for me even in Android Studio 3.0
It started working only after I checked "Show alternative source switcher"  in Settings.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBWo4.png)

Comment: I'm on Android Studio 3.5.3 and that option is already checked. Running on an API 21 device with 29 compile target, the debugger takes me to the mismatched API 29 source and doesn't show the source switcher. All sources supported by the app are installed.

Comment: Doesn't help me either.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try to debug into the source on an emulator that is running an android 5.0.x Lollipop image? Does it highlight the correct source? I have been struggling with this as well, and I reached the conclusion that the problem is due to customizations to the android source by the hardware vendor.

I have been trying to step through the android source code on a samsung device running 4.4.2 KitKat. Some files line up well, some are off by a few lines, and the rest are way out of whack. Instrumentation.java is one that I routinely find myself in. It is off by 5 lines or so.

So why do I think the vendor customized the android source? I stepped through application startup in ActivityThread.java and Instrumentation.java. The debugger will still step correctly even though the source doesn't line up. I cross referenced the routine I was in with android source code on grepcode.com. Eventually I see the debugger step into a function call that is not present in any version of the java file posted on grepcode.

Here is a specific example: ActivityThread.HandleLaunchActivity. I witnessed the debugger making these calls

```
unscheduleGcIdler          : present in android source
intent.getWindowStyle      : not present. Samsung customization?
handleConfigurationChanged : present
```

If I am right, then the debugger should step through an emulated image correctly, since it won't contain vendor customized code.

Comment: It is the case that its a vendor specific build and therefore isn't lining up. The most success I've had is via Genymotion running 5.0. Genymotion runs AOSP and it lines up perfectly. Its incredibly invaluable when you don't know what the f*ck your ListView is doing to screw up your row views of example.