# Android Studio: How to debug older version of Android SDK step-by-step

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have an Android project targetting the Android SDK v21. Now I need to debug it on a device with Android 4.4 (i.e. SDK v20). How do I tell Android Studio to attach an older version of the source to the internal classes so that I can step through them?

Comment: It may be temporary solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30054969/939193.

Comment: I see that if you set the compileSdkVersion to 20, it is using the source from 20 only.

Comment: @cypressious, is your project is on the air, meaning is on googles market? Can you supply the exception you get? is it for a specific brand (LG, Samsung etc), Samsung for example are changing  the os android system on their devices?  

In order to Debug it on a lower version, you can install Genymotion and run your app on it while you are on debug mode inside android studio.
The free version of Genymotion gives you support for all android 4.0 and above and i think 2.2 is also included.

You must know where your app crashes in order to not waste valuable time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android studio shows sources from API of compileSdkVersion when debugging on device with older API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671859/android-studio-shows-sources-from-api-of-compilesdkversion-when-debugging-on-dev)

Comment: There's a bug filed at google for that: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183976

Answer (score 7):

Here the best solution is to set compile SDK version to 20. So that build tools will compile your project using SDK version 20 and you can debug your app.

[image: Setting Compile SDK version]

When you use several modules in your project you need to set same compile SDK version to each module.

Comment: Well, that won't work for any project that uses recent APIs since it won't compile anymore...

Answer (score 5):

I can not confirm my answer works, but it is working for me.

I replace my **compileSdkVersion**, **buildToolsVersion**, **minSdkVersion**  and **targetSdkVersion** with new one like following in my **build.gradle** file.

```
android {
      compileSdkVersion 22
      buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mytest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
         }  
   }
}
```

After changing it, you may not need to convert old to new or new to old sdk component.

Answer (score 4):

You need to open module settings (Right click on your app module and select Open Module Settings or just select module and press ⌘ + ↓ on Mac)

And select `compileSdk` and `buildTools` to v20

Another way to do it is to open `build.gradle` file for the "app" module to change `compileSdk` and `buildTools`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain little before the solution.

Google provides the SDK APIs in the form of JAR (android.jar) files. The JAR files are stored at `SDK LOCATION\platforms\android-API#`. 
    For example the **android.jar** file for the Android 4.4(Kitkat) API-19 is located at `YOUR SDK LOCATION\platforms\android-19\android.jar`.

The Gradle compilation with the Android Studio uses the `compileSdkVersion` field in the `build.gradle` to select a specific  **android.jar** for the compilation. 
    
     **What is `compileSdkVersion`?**

- The version of the API the app is compiled against.
- This means you can compile and use Android API features included in that version of the API
- All the previous version features are also included during compilation.
- If you try and use API 21 feature, such as `public void openCamera (String cameraId, CameraDevice.StateCallback callback, Handler handler)` 
              Added in API level 21 but set compileSdkVersion to 20, you will get a compilation error.
- If you set compileSdkVersion to 21 you can still run the app on a API 20 device as long as your app's execution paths do not attempt to invoke any APIs specific to API 21.

**How to set `compileSdkVersion`?**
    There are two ways

[image: compileSdkVerion]
    
**1. Selecting API from the GUI**

1) Select "File->Project Structure..."
        2) Select "app->Properties"
        3) Set the "Compile Sdk Verion" from the drop down box to the required SDK version.
        4) "compileSdkVersion" will be set automatically in the "app" module's
        "build.gradle" file.

**2. Setting the API in the `gradle.build` file**

1) Open the `build.gradle` file of the "app" module
        2) Set the `compileSdkVersion` to required value such as 19 for the API#19.

I hope that helps...
    Happy Coding...

Comment: This is a solution yes. If you attempt to do this when also using the appcompat support library, you will get massive compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was to add a new module (Android Library) to the project and set the compile SDK to the requested api level. That way you can still compile your main app with the original SDK level but still get the sources integrated with your debugging Android version.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new Android Virtual Device with the preferred API level and debug the application on it.

Comment: There is a bug in my application that only happens on Android 4.4. I need to step through the platform code to trace it.

Comment: What happens when the bug occurs? Does it crash?

Comment: Post your logcat when it happens.

Comment: The answer doesn't give any explanation how to use Android Studio for debug step-by-step an older version of the source of Android.

Comment: @cypressious, I agree with rasmete. is it happen for all Android 4.4 devices or for a specific brand? if it's for all brands using AVD or Genymotion will help you a lot to debug the problem. if it's for a specfic brand you'll have to get a device for it (there are few Internet services that renting out devices with cost). Anyway you check also grepcode.com to see if there is something worng in a certain SDK method. If you don't find the problem I recommend to insert a try catch mechanism inside your code in order to deal with it inside your project.

Answer (score -1):

Simply open module settings and change **compileSdk** and **buildTools** to v20